# Svelte tutorial vim keybinding for command mode

Tags: svelte

When setting, via the URL parameter vim=true, the vim keybindings in the svelte tutorial at learn.svelte.dev, I cannot find any indication of the keybinding to exit insert mode into command mode. Esc just deselects the window, and typical choices like jj, jk, Ctrl-[, don't seem to work either.

Love that the bindings are available, but need clarity on the mode switchers.

I tried Esc, jj, jk, Ctrl-[. Esc simply deselected the editor window.

Comment: `esc` and `ctrl-[` work for me in firefox, chrome, and safari on MacOS.  What browser and environment are you using?

Comment: @possum : Thanks it was my mistake. A silly conflict with a vimuim browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

It was an interaction with my vimium browser extension. Disabling it resolved the conflict with Esc.